# Standard error of marginal effect for binary/categorical variable

Tags: bootstrap, standard-error, delta-method

The delta method/bootstrap method is used to obtain the standard error of marginal effect in case of limited dependent variable model (like tobit model). I have seen these being applied for the continuous variables, but my question is whether these can be also applied for categorical variables (say with 4 categories) or binary variables (say only with two categories). Please suggest academic papers if it is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the formulas on page 324 of Tamás Bartus' ["Estimation of Marginal Effects Using Margeff"](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0086) from Stata Journal. The formulas and explanations are not Stata-specific.

Stata now handles these calculations using the `margins` command.